# How do I get rid of this White Box?

Tags: html

I am trying my best to figure this out. It is mostly an annoyance, but if I can get it gone, I would LOVE to see it disappear!

I have this code that I obtained from elsewhere. Within it, there is the white bordered box, as you see in the photo. I have tried to figure out where it is by just simply removing bits of code that I think it is, but to no avail. Who knows what it is, and how can I get rid of it?

Also, while we're at it, how can I:

A) Limit the formula code to:

1. Only give rounded numbers (up/down based on the decimal)
2. Limit to only 2 decimal places.

B) Move the Entry boxes and the box text around to look much less messy?

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Technical Diving and Recreational - Nitrox Calculator</TITLE>
<META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<META 
content="nitrox calculator." 
name=description>
<META 
content="nitrox calculator" name=keywords>
<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="Dreamweaver MX">
<script language=javascript type="text/javascript"> 
function MOD_CALC() 
    {
    a = document.MOD.num1.value 
    b = document.MOD.num2.value
    if(a*1<1) { c = a * 1 } 
    else { c = a * 1 / 100}
    d = b * 1
    x = ((d/c)-1)*33
    // document.write(x)
    document.MOD.ans.value = x
    }

</script>
<style>
  body {font-family:arial; font-size:12}
  input {background-color:#8b0000}
  blockquote {font-colour:white; font-size:9}
  hr {color:white}
  a {color:white; font-size=14; TEXT-DECORATION:NONE}   
</style>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR=#454343 FONT FACE="ARIAL">
<CENTER>
<TABLE WIDTH=800 BORDER=0 CELLPADDING=0 CELLSPACING=0>
<TR>
                 <FONT FACE="ARIAL" SIZE=+1 COLOR=white></FONT></TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE WIDTH=800 BORDER=0 CELLPADDING=10 CELLSPACING=0>
<TR BGCOLOR=#8b0000>
        
    <TD WIDTH=250 ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=MIDDLE> <FONT SIZE=2 FACE=ARIAL COLOR=silver> 
      <h1>MOD CALCULATOR</h1>
            <p>
            <blockquote>
    
            </blockquote>
      </FONT> <br>
      
    </TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</TABLE>
<TABLE WIDTH=500 BORDER=0 CELLPADDING=0 CELLSPACING=0>
<TR BGCOLOR=#993e3e>
<TD>
<CENTER>
<p>
<table width=80% border=0 cellspacing=15>
    </TR>
    </form>
    <!-- ********************************** MOD ******************* -->
    <form name="MOD">
    <tr>
        <td colspan=4 align=left valign=middle>
            <hr size=25>
            <b>Maximum Operation Depth for Nitrox Mixes</b>
        </TD>
    </TR>
    <tr>
        <td align=right valign=middle>
            Nitrox Mix:
        </TD>
        <td align=left valign=middle>
            <input type="text" id="num1" size="4"> %
        </TD>
        <td align=center valign=middle rowspan=2>
            <input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="MOD_CALC()">
        </TD>
        <td align=center valign=middle rowspan=2>
            MOD is &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <br><input type="text" id="ans" size="10" >&nbsp;fsw  
        </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <td align=right valign=top>
            Partial Pressure: 
        </TD>
        <td align=left valign=top>
            <input type="text" id="num2" Size="4"> PPO2
        </TD>
    </TR>
    </form>
</table>
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Aside note: most of the styling attributes you've embedded in your tags are deprecated. Strip them out and replace with CSS.

Comment: Wherever you got that code from should be shut down. It's ancient. As the previous commenter noted, many of the tags are now obsolete, plus you should never use tables for layout. Use tables for tabular data. Use CSS for layout. It's 2023, not 1996

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular Not deprecated anymore. Now marked obsolete.

Comment: @j08691 yeah, I kinda figured it was ancient. I myself don't really dabble in html, css, or anything related to hard-coding websites. I just use website builders. Honestly, I can't even remember what I typed into google that brought me to the code in the first place. But let me just say, it was definitely old code. I actually improved the look of the original a little lol. All I know is the business doesn't exist anymore, and the website actually redirects to some business in arizona.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your HTML is full of errors. To delete the whitebox just remove the hr size=25

```js
    function MOD_CALC() {
      a = document.MOD.num1.value
      b = document.MOD.num2.value
      if (a * 1 < 1) {
        c = a * 1
      } else {
        c = a * 1 / 100
      }
      d = b * 1
      x = ((d / c) - 1) * 33
      // document.write(x)
      document.MOD.ans.value = x
    }
```

```css
    body {
      font-family: arial;
      font-size: 12
    }
    
    input {
      background-color: #8b0000
    }
    
    blockquote {
      font-colour: white;
      font-size: 9
    }
    
    hr {
      color: white
    }
    
    a {
      color: white;
      font-size=14;
      TEXT-DECORATION: NONE
    }
```

```html
enter image description here
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

<HTML>

<HEAD>
  <TITLE>Technical Diving and Recreational - Nitrox Calculator</TITLE>
  <META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"/>
  <META content="nitrox calculator." name=description/>
  <META content="nitrox calculator" name=keywords/>
  <META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="Dreamweaver MX"/>
  
  
</HEAD>

<BODY BGCOLOR=#454343 FONT FACE="ARIAL">
  <CENTER>
    <TABLE WIDTH=800 BORDER=0 CELLPADDING=0 CELLSPACING=0>
      <TR>
      <TD>
        <FONT FACE="ARIAL" SIZE=+1 COLOR=white></FONT>
        </TD>
      </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE WIDTH=800 BORDER=0 CELLPADDING=10 CELLSPACING=0>
      <TR BGCOLOR=#8b0000>

        <TD WIDTH=250 ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=MIDDLE>
          <FONT SIZE=2 FACE=ARIAL COLOR=silver>
            <h1>MOD CALCULATOR</h1>
            <p>
              <blockquote>

              </blockquote>
          </FONT> <br>

        </TD>
      </TR>
    </TABLE>
    
    <TABLE WIDTH=500 BORDER=0 CELLPADDING=0 CELLSPACING=0>
      <TR BGCOLOR=#993e3e>
        <TD>
          
            
              
              </TD>
      </TR>
      </form>
      <!-- ********************************** MOD ******************* -->
      <form name="MOD">
        <tr>
          <td colspan=4 align=left valign=middle>
           <!-- <hr size=25> -->
            <b>Maximum Operation Depth for Nitrox Mixes</b>
          </TD>
        </TR>
        <tr>
          <td align=right valign=middle>
            Nitrox Mix:
          </TD>
          <td align=left valign=middle>
            <input type="text" id="num1" size="4"> %
          </TD>
          <td align=center valign=middle rowspan=2>
            <input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="MOD_CALC()">
          </TD>
          <td align=center valign=middle rowspan=2>
            MOD is &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <br><input type="text" id="ans" size="10">&nbsp;fsw
          </TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <td align=right valign=top>
            Partial Pressure:
          </TD>
          <td align=left valign=top>
            <input type="text" id="num2" Size="4"> PPO2
          </TD>
        </TR>
      </form>
      </table>
      </TD>
      </TR>
    </TABLE>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Answer (score 2):

this line is causing it:

```
<hr size=25>
```